# Is there a general formula for creating close approximations of regular polygons on a regular lattice?

Tags: geometry

Prompted by the question [What regular polygons can be constructed on the points of a regular orthogonal grid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62407/what-regular-polygons-can-be-constructed-on-the-points-of-a-regular-orthogonal-gr):

A regular octagon can be approximated on a quad lattice (grid) to about $1\text{%}$ error by knowing that the length of the diagonal of a square is $\sqrt{2}$ (~$1.414$) times as long as its side.  With that information we can draw a "regular" octagon by marking the four lattice points 7 orthogonal lengths from a center point and marking the four lattice points 5 diagonal lengths from the same center point.

Is there a general rule that can be applied to create close approximations of other regular polygons on a quad-lattice (triangle, pentagon, enneagon, decagon, dodecagon, etc.)?

Comment: You can approximate any regular polygon to any desired (relative) tolerance simply by making it large enough compared to the grid. It's just a matter of rounding each corner to the nearest grid point ...

Comment: @Henning Makholm:  I understand that. The example I gave for the octagon is relatively simple.  Is there a simple method for determining the optimal points for other polygons, especially those that are not multiples of 4?

Comment: The real challenge is to produce best-possible approximations relative to the size of the grid.  This is related to simultaneous diophantine approximation.

Comment: How do you measure the "closeness" of an approximation?

Comment: I think my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251555/drawing-approximated-regular-shapes-on-square-grid/3067129#3067129 might answer this question.

Comment: @Timothy I don't see how it does, but please feel free to expand to an answer here ;)

Comment: BTW, this question is related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150938/regular-lattice-polygons